# Managing Schema Migration with Shared Objects in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my current job, we're faced with a migration challenge. We have a working application that we want to migrate to a new version. During the transition, we need both the old and new versions of the app to remain functional. Our backend relies on an Oracle database, and we've set up two separate schemas: SCHEMA1 for the old app and SCHEMA2 for the new version.

Our goal is to share most of the database objects between the two schemas, allowing for a smooth migration process. However, we need to exclude a couple of tables, let's call them table_1 and table_2, from the shared setup. Each schema should have its own version of these tables.

After some research, I came across the idea of using Oracle synonyms to achieve this. I've successfully set up synonyms to share objects between the schemas, and it's working as expected. However, I'm curious if there are alternative approaches that I might not have discovered during my search.

Comment: If you must use the same database and use schema separation, then synonyms make the most sense. As long as your code doesn't interrogate the dictionary about its objects, you should be fine using that method. Most shops however would typically have a test database and a prod database with the same schema name and migrate that way.